# why do we even need VPTR?

Tags: c++, vptr

And why don't we use the same method for non virtual functions?

I mean, why do we use virtual functions in that way? Can't we just use them as non-virtaul ones and override them?

And if this method is saving us time/space or what ever, why don't we use the same method for non-virtual functions? I mean it would make sense that there would be one table of functions for a specific class.

Anyway, thanks in advance, I am just a bit confused.

Comment: GMan? [Are you kidding?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman)

Comment: IS this a different GMan than normal?

Comment: I'm certain this is a different GMan than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman

Comment: @sbi @Martin @Fred: It's not me.

Comment: @GMan: So you're not [GMan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/242981/gman), then? `:)` This _is_ confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have run-time polymorphism without using a level of indirection. That's what the vptr is for.

The vptr is not used for non-polymorphic functions because that indirection costs something. The C++ philosophy is that you don't pay for what you don't use.

EDIT:

Here's some info on how virtual tables work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table

Comment: Where can I find more information on the another level of indirection for run-time polymorphism?

EDIT: And on the C++ philosophy for that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: @GMan, just try to get the same behaviour using C, you will most likely end up using tables of function pointers.

Comment: @GMan: From the C++ origianl design doc: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/rules.pdf <quote>That is, the zero-overhead principle: “what you don’t use, you don’t pay for”</quote>

Comment: @Martin York: Great link. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler essentially generates a direct call to non-virtual methods.  With a virtual method call, the compiler generates code to lookup the address of the method and then makes a call to that address.  Thus, it is, in theory, at least one more lookup when calling a virtual function.  There would be no reason to incur that cost otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Using vptr allows method resolution based on object type rather than variable type. Not using vptr makes method calls faster. The C++ designers decided to allow the convenience of virtual functions but not require the performance penalty for other functions.